# How to make work such a command: "$ sudo php -v"?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, php, php-cli

I have installed and working PHP53 from source.

PATH is set in `~/.profile` like this: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/php53/bin`

```
$ php -v # works good
```

BUT:

```
$ sudo php -v # sudo: php: command not found
```

I needed to run `sudo composer self-update`, and it gave me a message:

```
/usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

$ composer -v # works good (installed globally by this manual https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally
```

In short:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I have similar problem with Apache22 `apachectl`, but I am using full path to run with sudo. But it is a workaround, and I'd like to know, how to make it work in common.

The problem is that `$ sudo php -v` and `sudo composer self-update` DOES NOT WORK.

**UPDATE:**
I added to /root/.profile new path to PHP53:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.


export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/php53/bin


if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi
```

mesg n

Then I rebooted OS, and here are results for various tests:

```
$ echo $PATH # /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/apache2_2/bin:/usr/local/php53/bin
$ php -v # works, as before
$ sudo php -v # "sudo: php: command not found"


$ sudo su
# echo $PATH # /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games , i.e. "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/php53/bin" did not have effect on $PATH.
# php -v # "The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install php5-cli"
# . /root/.profile 
# php -v # "PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Sep 24 2015 13:05:17) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

BUT:

```
$ sudo php -v # still, "sudo: php: command not found"
```

As a little relief,

```
$ sudo /usr/local/php53/bin/php -v # is working 
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Sep 24 2015 13:05:17) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Seems like we have at least two problems:

1. export $PATH in /root/.profile does not have effect (tested after OS reboot!)
2. even when I do `# . /root/.profile`, `sudo php -v` still does not work.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 with last updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is down to how `sudo` defines its `PATH`. Basically, it will either take the `PATH` of the user calling it, or if so configured, it will read what is set in the `secure_path` variable of `/etc/sudoers`.

So, you have two choices:

1. Add the directory where the `php` binary is located to the secure path. Run `sudo visudo`, find this line:

   ```
   Defaults   secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$
   ```

   and change it to

   ```
   Defaults   secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/php53/bin:$
   ```
2. Simply comment out the `secure_path` line and have `sudo` share the same path as the invoking user. This is not the safest of choices of course, but it's up to you. To do this, run `sudo visudo` and add a `#` to the beginning of the line:

   ```
   # Defaults   secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$
   ```

Save the file and exit `visudo` and you should be able to run `sudo php -v` as expected.

Comment: terdon, +1, thanks! Tested both options, decided to stick with second one for now.

Comment: need to open a lots of link to find the solution then came to this answer. you're just saved my day! thank you! I prefer solution #1